# Python: Convert several/multiple .docx file from ANSI to UTF-8 on a particular folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I am not very good programmer. But I want to make a py code that may convert several/multiple .docx file from ANSI to UTF-8, from a particular folder.

I will start with this. But I don't know further, how to select files from folder. Maybe someone helps me a little bit.

```
from unidecode import unidecode

python2_text = docx_paragraph.text
unicode_text = python2_text.decode("utf-8", "replace") if isinstance(python2_text , str) else python2_text
unidecode(unicode_text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
import os
import zipfile
import io
import chardet

# Set the folder path where the .docx files are located
folder_path = os.getcwd()

# Loop through all files in the folder
for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith(".docx"):
        # Open the .docx file
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path) as docx_file:
                # Read the contents of the document.xml file
                xml_content = docx_file.read('word/document.xml')
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error opening {file_path}: {e}")
            continue

        # Detect the current encoding of the file
        detected_encoding = chardet.detect(xml_content)['encoding']
        print(f"{file_path} is encoded in {detected_encoding}")
        # If the detected encoding is not UTF-8, save the file in UTF-8 format
        if detected_encoding != "utf-8":
            new_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "_utf8.docx"
            new_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, new_filename)
            with zipfile.ZipFile(new_file_path, "w") as docx_file:
                # Write the contents of the modified document.xml file
                docx_file.writestr('word/document.xml', xml_content.decode(detected_encoding).encode('utf-8'))
            print(f"Converted {file_path} from {detected_encoding} to UTF-8 and saved as {new_file_path}")
        else:
            print(f"{file_path} is already in UTF-8 format")
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'original_encoding'`

See print screen: https://snipboard.io/iN3fx6.jpg

Comment: What python do you use? The question is for 3.x but maybe you meant python 2?

Comment: I have the same error. I use Python, Version 3.1.0  And PyScripter version 4.2.1.0

Comment: No, I believe the problem is this: `original_encoding` What does this ? was not declared what it does

Comment: You are right. It was older version that it was working. So can you give me some files for testing? I have only utf-8 right now.

Comment: ok, I share 3 docx files here for testing. Please download here: https://files.fm/u/zvfmf5e9g

Comment: tell me please if you managed to make a better version that works

Comment: The files appear to bu UTF-8.

Comment: maybe, change it yourself to ANSI (you can copy and make a new file with the same content) , then test it.

Comment: I googled that all docx files are utf-8 so maybe you need doc or txt files?

Comment: both extension, but I believe txt files will be a better solution.  Yes, if you can test and add a second answer for converting all txt files to UTF-8, it will be great

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Andreas  Yes, if you can test and add a second answer for converting all txt files to UTF-8, it will be great